# Upgrading sqlite3 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, centos7

Does anyone know how to upgrade sqlite3 on Centos7. The repos only have up to version 3.7.

I downloaded the source code and compiled. Replaced binaries. If I type sqlite/sqlite3 --version then it's 3.31.

If I run rails then it's stuck at 3.7.

DNF is stuck on 3.7 too.

I read that Centos7 stays at this version. There's no easy upgrade path to Centos8 without reinstall so trying to avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall the package from Centos. Then, do a normal source install of `sqlite` afterwards.

Comment: You could install a second version of sqlite to another path when building the source; a bit fuzzy and dirty but coluld solve your problem.